# Widget not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, orchardcms

I made a new widget following the [LatestTwitter](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/01/21/Writing-an-Orchard-widget-LatestTwitter.aspx) example from Maarten Balliauw.

My project is an almost exact copy of it, but using diferent namespaces, class names, etc.

I can enable the module and add the widget to the layer.

However, after adding the widget (which generates a sucessful notification message) I can observe that no record has been inserted into the database table that should hold this record.

And when I try to edit the widget I get the error:

```
NHibernate.MappingException was unhandled by user code
  Message=No persister for: MyNamespace.MyWidgetRecord
  Source=NHibernate
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName)
(...)
```

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting the module from scratch, and now it works. The original problem remains a mistery...

Answer (score 0):

its probably one of the following

- hbm.xml not set to embedded resource
- `MyWidgetRecordMap : Classmap<MyWidgetRecord>` not public
- hbm or Mapping class not added to the configuration

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. Looks like this is more Orchard specific than NHibernate.

Comment: maybe MyWidgetRecord must be public?